Adaptive rate limiting in Nginx?
I’ve tried googling this question and even using ChatGPT and Google Gemini to try to get an answer but they said it's impossible with Nginx.
Scenario
Suppose I have a web app with 20,000 users and the hosting service only provides up to 10 Gbps (maximum) of server bandwidth.
Logged In Users
Out of the 20,000 users, there are 5,000 registered users who are allowed a guaranteed 1 Mbps bandwidth per user. Thus, at 100% load with each user consuming 1 Mbps, they will consume the 5 Gbps for such a group.
Visitors
The rest of the user-base that are not registered users, which is composed of 15,000 users, are visitors who rarely use the site save for some peak access time. I plan on dividing the remaining 50% bandwidth for an indeterminate number of visitors which may peak at the said 15,000 users. They are also okay with sharing bandwidth and slower connections in cases of peak times.
Goal: Rate Limiting Setup
How I can set up rate limiting for the visitors such that the bandwidths are shared among the users?

If there is only 1 active visitor, I want to set a hard upper limit of 1 Mbps for visitors.
If there is only 2 active visitor, I want to set a limit relative to the maximum limit in (1) which is 5 Gbps, thus, 5 Gbps / 2 = 2.5 Gbps which is still above 1 Mbps cap, 2 active visitors is also capped at 1 Mbps
If there are 1,000 active visitors at a time, I want to set still limit relative to 5 Gbps, 5 Gbps / 1000 = 5 Mbps which is also still above the 1 Mbps cap, so I will also cap it at 1 Mbps
If there are 5,000 active visitors at a time, the 1 Mbps cap will be hit, since 5 Gbps / 5000 is 1 Mbps.
If there are 15,000 active visitors at a time (the prospect), they will share 333 Kbps (relatively slow, but say the site is an SPA that only loads raw data and very few compressed images).

How can I achieve this rate limiting strategy in nginx?
